# Bash Script | How to read an input through stdin in an array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, input, stdin

This is how the script gets started over the terminal:

```
echo 'username1 username2 username3' | ./security_check.sh
```

---

This is the part of the program which should read the stdin and put it into an array:

```
while read -r line_input
do
    i_users[i]=$line_input
    i+=1
done
```

---

`IFS` is not set to something different in this script.

After the input is saved in an array it should be able to get printed like this:

```
for i in ${i_users[@]}
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

---

This script takes the whole input through stdin and puts it just in `i_users[0]`.
How can I fix this? The array `i_users` was declared with `declare -a i_users` at the beginning of the script

Comment: Use `read -a` to read words into an array.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately.
if i use: 
while read -a line
do
i_users[i]=$line_input
done

echo ${i_users[2]}

echo wont give a variable back.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

- `while read -r line_input` is going to read data one **line** at a time
- the script has **one** line of input (`username1 username2 username3`)
- so the array ends up with a single entry (index=0 / value=`username1 username2 username3`)

To break the single line of input into separate array entries you have a few options, one being the `read -a` suggested by @choroba:

```
$ cat security_check.sh
#!/bin/bash

read -ra i_users
typeset -p i_users
```

Running OP's example script call:

```
$ echo 'username1 username2 username3' | ./security_check.sh
declare -a i_users=([0]="username1" [1]="username2" [2]="username3")
```

**NOTE**: This works for a single line of input (as shown in OP's sample script call).